# How to manage multiple socket ports of React & Nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have multiple list like this, when click on tab will load relevant data in api, but per tab will have different socket ports. Example: STO is 1111, HNX is 2222...Client has a socket event that will update symbol in list.

The problem is I have a watchlist that add symbol from tabs but it comes from different socket ports. So how could I manage socket connections ?

Is it better to manage it in the client or backend ?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYXWU.jpg)

Thanks all.